# python timed menu option

Tags: python, menu, timed

I have a python program that grabs an ftp directory listing every ten seconds.

```
While True:
  ...
  ftp.nlst()
  time.sleep(refresh_delay)
  ...
```

I want to be able to press 'q' or 'r' to quit or restart during the program's `time.sleep(refresh_delay)` function call . The problem with Ctrl-C during the program means that the ftp.quit() function isn't called and leaves the connection open until timeout.

For comparative purposes, the MS command line utility `choice` does this via:

```
choice /c QRN /t 10 /d N /M "Quit, Restart, Do Nothing"
```

I'd like the options to be hidden if possible, but it isn't mandatory.

Comment: "Ctrl-C during the program ... leaves the connection open until timeout." Respectfully, I don't believe you. With no Ctrl-C handler installed, Ctrl-C causes the program to exit, which closes all of its open file descriptors, which terminates the TCP session, which terminates the FTP connection. Do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: I do not have evidence. I can't see the connections because i don't have administration privileges on the FTP server. But it seems that Ctrl-C to break the program would cause something "ugly" on the remote end.
I did try this on my Ubuntu Server and using ctrl-C did close the connections. I believe the intended FTP server is a windows environment. Are you certain this exhibits the same behavior?

Comment: If it doesn't behave the way I describe, then something is broken.

Comment: Incidentally, you can catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception and then execute cleanup code and then re-raise it.

Answer (score 1):

I fear you will need two threads: One that does the ftp-listing and goes to sleep. And another that gets user input and maybe ends and joins the first thread.